# Interaction between \hdotsfor and colortbl: Bug/Feature?

Tags: amsmath, colortbl

When using package `colortbl`, the command `\hdotsfor` fails (partially), leaving too much white space before and after the dotted part. The mwe

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}    
\[
\begin{pmatrix}
    1&a_{11}&\dots&a_{1n}\\
    \hdotsfor{4}\\
    1&a_{r1}&\dots&a_{rn}
    \end{pmatrix} = r.
\]
\end{document}
```

produces

[image: hdostsfor fails]

Removing the package `colortbl` makes everything right:

[image: hdotsfor is OK]

I understand this may be related to `\leader`s and/or *glue*, which **are** explicitly mentioned in `colortbl`'s documentation, so maybe this is a feature and not a bug.

**Question:** is there an easy workaround, bar removing `colortbl`?

Comment: there are _only_ features, never _bugs_ in my packages! (should be easy enough to make a compatible hdots, will look)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: I thought so, thanks a lot for taking the time on this one!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Since `\hdotsfor` is only really designed for the AMS alignments, and `colortbl` colouring doesn't really work for them, I think the simplest is to add

```
\makeatletter

\def\hdots@for#1#2{\multicolumn{#2}c%
  {\m@th\dotsspace@1.5mu\mkern-#1\dotsspace@
   \xleaders\hbox{$\m@th\mkern#1\dotsspace@.\mkern#1\dotsspace@$}%
           \hskip\z@\@plus 1filll
   \mkern-#1\dotsspace@}%
   }
\makeatother
```

to your preamble after loading `amsmath` that makes these stretch with `filll` rather than `fill` glue which means that in the battle of elasticity with the `colortbl` the dots win.

If you wanted a version of `\hdotfill` that worked even if there was a colortbl panel behind it then it would require a bit more work.

Comment: This is good enough for me, I don't think I'll (ever) need a colored background to a `\hdotsfor`... :)

Answer (score 1):

The same answer of @DavidCarlisle but using [`etoolbox`](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/etoolbox/etoolbox.pdf) and its command `\patchcmd` to *patch* (*replace*) code in `amsmath.sty`

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\hdots@for}{\hfill}{\hskip\z@\@plus 1filll}{}{}
\makeatother
```

This must be put *after* of `amsmath` too.