# colortbl changes the width of a multicolumn-ed \dotfill and the page size

Tags: paper-size, multicolumn, colortbl

The following MWE works as expected: the `\dotfill` "line" spans the entire tabular.

```
\documentclass{article}
% \usepackage{colortbl}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{p{.45\linewidth}p{.45\linewidth}}
  aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa & bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb \\
  \multicolumn{2}{c}{\dotfill}
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

But, as soon as `colortbl` package is loaded, the dotted "line" is dramatically shortened.

Another very strange phenomenon is that the page size is not the same:

- without `colortbl`, it is 595.276 x 841.89 pts (A4),
- with `colortbl`, it is 612 x 792 pts (letter).

Note: this happens with an up to date `TeX Live 2014`, with the following list files (when `colortbl` is loaded):

```
 *File List*
 article.cls    2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
  size10.clo    2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX file (size option)
colortbl.sty    2012/02/13 v1.0a Color table columns (DPC)
   array.sty    2014/10/28 v2.4c Tabular extension package (FMi)
   color.sty    2014/10/28 v1.1a Standard LaTeX Color (DPC)
   color.cfg    2007/01/18 v1.5 color configuration of teTeX/TeXLive
  pdftex.def    2011/05/27 v0.06d Graphics/color for pdfTeX
infwarerr.sty    2010/04/08 v1.3 Providing info/warning/error messages (HO)
 ltxcmds.sty    2011/11/09 v1.22 LaTeX kernel commands for general use (HO)
supp-pdf.mkii
 ***********
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`colortbl` documents that there are severe restrictions on the use of stretch glue, and leaders such as `\dotfill` are essentially generalised  glue in tex.

See [Interaction between \hdotsfor and colortbl: Bug/Feature?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/52108/interaction-between-hdotsfor-and-colortbl-bug-feature)

The page size thing is because pdftex.def sets the `\pdfpageheight` and width primitives that tells pdftex the page size that latex is using. by default that is US letter unless you use `\documentclass[a4paper]{article}`

See [graphicx (or graphics) package distorts format](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/152249/graphicx-or-graphics-package-distorts-format/169323#169323)

Comment: For the first problem, thanks to your link, I managed by patching `\dotfill` macro with `\hskip\z@\@plus 1filll` in place of `\hfill` (either directly or via `etoolbox`' `\patchcmd`). I hope I won't be bitten by side effects. For the second problem, I beg your pardon for having blamed `colortbl` :)

Comment: @DenisBitouzé well I probably put the settings in pdftex.def (I can't remember, it may have been Sebastian:-)

Comment: OK, so I won't blame `colortbl` but I will blame its author ;) BTW, now these two troubles have been identified (I don't pretend "by me"), is there a way to fix them for the future?

Comment: @DenisBitouzé the page size isn't something that needs fixing, it's just historical that latex defaults to US letter but in most of the world people set pdf generation to default to a4 and so you need `[a4paper]` to get things in sync. Not ideal but you can't erase history.  for fill glue it just doesn't work in colortbl. so you can't use `\hfill` and there is not much I can do about that. You can use `\hspace{0pt plus 1filll}` if there is no coloured background and similarly you could define a lll version of `\dotfill` (which is safer than patching dotfill) if there is colour then its harder

Comment: When you say "[I] can't use `\hfill`", do you mean just in `tabular`s? OK for avoid patching `\dotfill` but, similarly, in which context is it "harder"? And what is a "lll" version: do you mean a personal macro `\mydotfill`?

Comment: @DenisBitouzé oh yes I just mean in tabular cells yes. You could call it `\dotfilll` which is what I'd call it. by `lll` I mean using `filll` glue instead of `fill` glue. `\dotfill` stretches like `0pt plus 1fill` so you want something the same that stretches like `0pt plus 1filll`